# Justify All Text in Microsoft Word VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am trying to create a word VBA that can justify all the text if the font size is 10, ignoring all the tables and shapes.
Some how, it doesn't work on large documents with thousands of paragraph as it will hang.
Anyway I can streamline this code to make it run more faster and efficient.

```
Sub JustifyAllTheText()
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim para   As Paragraph
    Dim searchRange As Range
    Set searchRange = Selection.Range
    searchRange.End = ActiveDocument.Content.End
    For Each para In searchRange.Paragraphs
        If para.Range.Font.Size = 10 And para.Range.Font.ColorIndex = wdBlack And Not para.Range.InlineShapes.count > 0 And Not para.Range.Information(wdWithInTable) Then
            para.Range.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphJustify
        End If
    Next para
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```vb
    Sub JustifyAllTheText()
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim para   As Paragraph
    Dim searchRange As Range
    Set searchRange = Selection.Range
    searchRange.End = ActiveDocument.Content.End
    For Each para In searchRange.Paragraphs
        If para.Range.Font.Size = 10 Then
        If para.Range.Font.ColorIndex = wdBlack Then
        If Not para.Range.InlineShapes.Count > 0 Then
        If Not para.Range.Information(wdWithInTable) Then
        para.Range.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphJustify
        End If
        End If
        End If
        End If
    Next para
End Sub
```

Comment: It works. Whats the rationale behind the nested if loop

Comment: @Alvin567 - Your code is slow because for each paragraph in the search range all four conditions have to be tested. By splitting out the conditions into separate If statements the code can move on more quickly if any of the tests fail, e.g. if the font size isn't 10 there is no need to test the other criteria so the code can move on to the next para in the loop.

Comment: Perfect explanation from @Timothy Rylatt, yes that's why the code is broken down to nested ifs .... so that if the 1st check is FALSE no need to check the rest 3 conditions .... glad that it helped