# Justify All Text except in line broken by a line break

Tags: vba, ms-word, line-breaks, justify

I'm new here so thank you in advance for your patience. Also, I'm not a native English speaker so some things might get lost in translation.

I found this wonderful vba macro to "Justify all text is Microsoft Word" [from Alvin567] and you all [1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63876973/19745654) and it works just as planned.

I would like to adapt it so that it doesn't justify paragraphs that has Shift+Enter (linebreak I think) in my document. I can't seem to find how to refer to that specific character, since it's different than "Chr(13)".

I'm usually good at adapting codes from the recording tool or find online what I'm looking for even though I never learned it through any courses, but with this one, I can't seem to figure it out on my own.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

So here is the code :

```
Sub JustifyAllTheText(control As IRibbonControl) 'Don't forget to link it with RibbonX
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim para   As Paragraph
    Dim searchRange As Range
    Set searchRange = Selection.Range
    searchRange.End = ActiveDocument.Content.End
For Each para In searchRange.Paragraphs
    If para.Range.Font.Size = 10 Then
    'If para.Range.Font.ColorIndex = wdBlack Then 'I don't need it but kept it just in case
    If Not para.Range.InlineShapes.Count > 0 Then
    'If Not para.Range.IsEndOfRowMark = True Then 'Added line to test linebreak but doesn't work to made into text
    If Not para.Range = vbLf Then
    If Not para.Range.Information(wdWithInTable) Then
    para.Range.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphJustify
    End If
    End If
    End If
    End If
Next para

End Sub
```

Thanks!

Comment: Justification in Word is a paragraph attribute. A line break is within a paragraph and so that line's justification cannot be set independently of the whole paragraph.

Comment: Thank you @Charles Kenyon, I understand what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

You *cannot* justify lines ending in manual line breaks via any of the paragraph justification options. Instead, you need to modify a compatibility setting, thus:

```
Sub Demo()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
ActiveDocument.Compatibility(wdExpandShiftReturn) = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Any lines you don't want to have justified that way will then require a tab to be inserted before the manual line break.

Moreover, you should not force the justification of paragraphs via code like:

```
para.Range.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphJustify
```

That is liable to lead to document bloat and, potentially, corruption. Rather, you should modify the underlying paragraph Style - which also means making the change once for all affected paragraphs throughout the document.

Comment: Thanks @macropod.I get the I could modify the Style, but it won't mind if there's a line break within it.
I get the I could modify the Style, but it won't mind if there's a line break within it. That's why I though that the macro found would be a great option to modifiy and justify just the paragraphs needed.
Why would this kind of macro lead to bloat/corruption please?
The point of using a macro to justify was to have less manual work to do on the document since we will be having new documents to work on instead of the previous way , which was the same one that would be modified over time.

Comment: «Why would this kind of macro lead to bloat/corruption please» Bloat, because Word has to track separately every paragraph where you override the Style with a different format. An increased risk of corruption is as per reported experience.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your help.

Since it wasn't a good thing to justify that way, I manage to get my result with a mix of a Find and replace macro to get rid of the Shift+Enter and they I modified the Normal style to justify it. Put them both together and added a button on my RibbonX custom tab. All in all, everthing ends up as it should be and we save time with the help of a button.

Thank you!

Comment: In this forum, to which you are new I realize, this should be posted as a comment or as an amendment/edit to your original question.

Answer (score -1):

You can check for
`If InStr(para.Range.Text, vbVerticalTab) = 0 Then`

If you replace your current codeline `If Not para.Range = vbLf Then` with this line, your macro will exlude paragraphs that have a soft return from applying wdAlignParagraphJustify

`vbVerticalTab` is equal to `chr(11)` which is in Word the "character" for `Shift+Enter`

Comment: I'm not sure how I should add this to the actual code. Should I use it on the 1st line just after For Each para In...? If I add it right there, nothing else works even if the macro runs to the end (I added a msgBox to confirm). If I write it with Not, macro works just as before but doesn't manage the Shift+Enter and even at the last argument before justifying, it doesn't seem to behave differently.

Do you have any other tips?

Comment: You have to replace the `If Not para.Range = vbLf Then` line with `If InStr(para.Range.Text, vbVerticalTab) = 0 Then`